# Vue - Adding background animation

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to add some background mp4/gif animation to my webpage, but for some reason it's not working - it only shows some black placeholder for (what seems to be) the animation.

This is the library I've tried to use: https://github.com/pespantelis/vue-videobg

Having followed the instructions, I've ended up with this (only showing relevant sections):

The `main.js` file:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line import/extensions
import VideoBg from 'vue-videobg';

Vue.component('video-bg', VideoBg);
```

The `Comp.Vue` component file:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-container fluid class="primary">
      <v-row>
        <v-col>
          <video-bg :sources="['../assets/witchcraft-magic.mp4']"
                    img="../assets/vast.png">
          </video-bg>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </div>
</template>
```

BTW the same outcome happened to me while trying using other libraries - for example https://github.com/avidofood/vue-responsive-video-background-player
so I guess there's something basic I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
:sources="[require('@/assets/witchcraft-magic.mp4')]"

:img="require('@/assets/img/vast.png')"
```

Comment: it's giving me all sort of eslint errors

Comment: Sory mate, i forgot quotes, try now pls

Comment: I've changed `poster` to `img` and now the png file is shown, but the animation is not displayed

Comment: It turns out all was missing was wrapping it with `[` and `]` `<video-bg :sources="[require('@/assets/witchcraft-magic.mp4')]">`

Comment: Nice mate, i will update answer for others, cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes .. in the path does not work. Try giving the complete path like

```
<video-bg :sources="['<project-name>/assets/witchcraft-magic.mp4']"
                img="<project-name>/assets/vast.png">
      </video-bg>
```

Comment: Sadly, it didn't work as well